# When I Run python shell, some errors happened

Tags: python, scipy

My python is 2.7.  And scipy is 0.18.1.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\59243\Desktop\icadenoise_dev\fastica.py", line 7, in <module>
from scipy.linalg import sqrtm, inv
ImportError: No module named scipy.linalg
>>>
```

Comment: How did you install SciPy? Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: have you tried `from scipy import linalg.sqrtm, linalg.inv`?

Comment: Do you have `numpy+mkl` installed? Try using [PIP](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/) to install scipy: `pip install scipy`.

Comment: I used"conda  install scipy".

Comment: @Ev. Kounis   yes i have

Comment: @Chris  conda  install scipy

Answer (score 0):

when I used `conda install scipy`, 
I got `# All requested packages already installed.

## packages in environment at C:\Users\59243:

#
scipy                     0.18.1              np112py27_1`

but when i used `pip install scipy`
The`Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\59243\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-gern63\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\59243\appdata\local\temp\pip-7zqhhb-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\59243\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-gern63\scipy\` error came out